# SQL - How to join two fields from the same table

Tags: mysql

I'm approaching to SQL code and I'm trying to create a query that join info from different table.
I have one table in which I have, in the same field, two information with two different keys. How can I join these info without duplicating rows?

Example:

Table 1

```
customer1 key1 key2 
customer2 key1 key2
```

Table2

```
info key1
info key2
```

My code is:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) 
customer1,
info as value1,
info as value2
from table1 
    left join table2 on table1.key1 = table2.key1 
        or table1.key2 = table2.key2
```

In this case the rows are duplicated. How can I do to have only one single row but with two info that I need from table2?

Many thanks

Comment: First-off, MySql doesn't have `top()` so have you TAGGED correctly?

Comment: @RiggsFolly - eh? that *would* be a syntax error

Comment: `table1.key1 = table2=key1 ` however most definitely is a syntax error

Comment: obviously been to long since I SQLServer'd

Comment: yes guys it's a syntax error, I mean table1.key1 = table2.key1

Comment: It's not clear what is the column names and what's the column values in your two tables. It looks like table 2 only has one `key` column, and it has two values `key1` or `key2`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `table2` only has one `key` column, not `key1` and `key2`. Those are values for the column in different rows.

You can join with the table multiple times. Use different aliases to distinguish them.

```
SELECT t1.customer, t2a.info AS value1, t2b.info AS value2
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2a ON t1.key1 = t2a.key
JOIN table2 AS t2b ON t1.key2 = t2a.key
```